# Filling out an Infopath form with the aid of a complex sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

I have a big Infopath form which is part of a complex workflow that involves collecting input and signatures from various users, as well as approvals.

Currently, that same workflow is being done manually — the Infopath form is actually a PDF form and the workflow steps are performed by the actual users who fill out the form, emailing it afterwards to whoever they think it may concern.

I'm on the process of automatizing this using our Sharepoint Server infrastructure, so the first thing was translating the PDF form to an Infopath one. The second would be to produce a Sharepoint workflow that would implement the business process of getting that form properly filled.

So my question is: is it possible to implement a Sharepoint Workflow that sends the full form to the correct users based on the information gathered by the form itself? Ideally, the form would be passed around using the rules defined in the workflow process, users would fill whatever necessary, submit the form and the workflow would continue based on whatever is filled. This form would not only be the initiator form, but the form to be handled in all the workflow tasks.

Breaking the form apart is not desirable as this would confuse our users, and some of them need the overview provided by the full form view. Also, I'd like to use Sharepoint as the form distributor, instead of the email service, if possible.

Any pointers in how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.
Here are the pointers in brief:

1. Create a content type with your infopath form as item form
2. Create a visual studio workflow that is associated to your content
   type
3. In the code of the workflow you can implement any rules of
   processing the form. you're able to get the form data from the list
   item you workflow runs in context of.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you mind explaining just a bit more those steps? Also, is Visual Studio absolutely necessary? Can Sharepoint Designer be used for the same purpose?

Comment: 1. here is a how to demo on the first point http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/demo-store-infopath-forms-in-a-document-library-on-a-sharepoint-site-HA010263674.aspx

Comment: 2. SharePoint designer might turn out sufficient in case your routing logic is simple enough to be implemented with SharePoint Designer activities

Comment: 3. see point 2. if you use SPD you can utilize it to operate on the item. similar approach is utilized in Visual Studio workflows with custom code. you can access item fields and analyse data and then rout the workflow to a required direction.